# Filter by attribute name

Tags: grid, filter

I've created a custom filter in manage products page and I want to filter from `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()` values by attribute name.

UPDATE:

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {

    if(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::CONFIG_ENABLED)) {
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
        ->joinField('qty',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left');

        if ($store->getId()) {
            $collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
            $adminStore = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
            $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
            $collection->joinAttribute('name', 'catalog_product/name', 'entity_id', null, 'inner', $adminStore);
            $collection->joinAttribute('custom_name', 'catalog_product/name', 'entity_id', null, 'inner', $store->getId());
            $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner', $store->getId());
            $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner', $store->getId());
            $collection->joinAttribute('price', 'catalog_product/price', 'entity_id', null, 'left', $store->getId());
        }
        else {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
            $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
            $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        }

        $filter = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameFilter(), null);
        if (!is_null($filter))  {
            $filter = $this->helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filter);
            if (isset($filter['attribute'])) {
                $attributeCode = $filter['attribute'];
                $collection->joinAttribute($attributeCode, 'catalog_product/'.$attributeCode, 'entity_id', null, 'left');
                $collection->addAttributeToSelect($attributeCode);

            }
        }

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
        $this->getCollection()->addWebsiteNamesToResult();
    } else {
        parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    return $this;
}

protected function _prepareColumns() {      
    parent::_prepareColumns();
    if(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::CONFIG_ENABLED)) {

        $ignoreAttributes = array('name', 'attribute_set_id', 'type_id', 'qty', 'price', 'status', 'visibility');

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
            ->addVisibleFilter();

        $result = array();   
        foreach ($collection as $model) {
            if(in_array($model->getAttributeCode(), $ignoreAttributes)) {
                continue;
            }
            $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
            $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(array($model->getAttributeCode()));
            $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($model->getAttributeCode(), array('gt' => 0));

            if(count($productCollection->getData()) > 0) {
                $result[$model->getAttributeCode()] = $model->getAttributeCode();
            }

        }

        $this->addColumn('attribute',
            array(
                'header'=> 'Attribute',
                'width' => '150px',
                'index' => 'attribute',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => $result,
                'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterHasAttributeCallback')

        ));


        $filter = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameFilter(), null);
        if (!is_null($filter))  {
            $filter = $this->helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filter);
            if (isset($filter['attribute'])) {
                $attributeCodeConfig = $filter['attribute'];

                $attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $attributeCodeConfig);

                $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
                $attributeData = $attribute->getData();
                $frontEndLabel = $attributeData['frontend_label'];

                $attributeOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
                $b = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute();
                $attributeOptions2 = array();
                foreach ($attributeOptions as $value) {
                    if(!empty($value['value'])) {
                        $attributeOptions2[$value['value']] = $value['label'];
                    }

                }


                if(count($attributeOptions2) > 0) {
                    $this->addColumn($attributeCodeConfig,
                        array(
                            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__($frontEndLabel),
                            'width' => '80px',
                            'index' => $attributeCodeConfig,
                            'type'  => 'options',
                            'options' => $attributeOptions2,

                    ));
                } else {
                    $this->addColumn($attributeCodeConfig,
                        array(
                            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__($frontEndLabel),
                            'width' => '80px',
                            'index' => $attributeCodeConfig,

                    ));
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}

protected function _filterHasAttributeCallback($collection, $column) {
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }
    // STILL DON'T KNOW HOW TO FILTER BY ATTRIBUTE NAME
    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where("main_table.? IS NOT NULL", $value);

    return $this;
}
```

// STILL DON'T KNOW HOW TO FILTER BY ATTRIBUTE NAME

```
$this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where("main_table.? IS NOT NULL", $value);
```

After I select the attribute name for example 'abc_color', I want to filter all the products that use attribute 'abc_color'.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? If yes, post that as well

Comment: Try removing "sku" from your array and execute again and see the error exists?

Comment: @Nidheesh Can you take a look? Thanks :D

Comment: Sure, but can you please clarify your requirement? Making the question a bit more clear will help others as well to contribute

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array($value))->addAttributeToFilter($value, array('gt' => 0));
```

Solved it :D

Comment: Though its your own question please provide more detail so , in future someone has same problem can take benifit from this